# Relation and Function in a language

Tags: logic, model-theory

At the very beginning of David Marker's book Model Theory, it defines a language to be given by a set of function symbols $F$ and a set of relation symbols R.

I am just wondering isn't a relation a kind of a function too? Is there a reason why the relation is differentiated from function?

Comment: if he gives them different names now, he will give them different uses later.

Comment: This is the usual definition of first-order *language*: connectives, quantifiers, variables, (individual) constants, function, relations. We can replace a $n$-ary function symbol with a $(n+1)$-ary relation one, but it is more convenient to have function symbols, like $+$ and $\times$ for arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is that in first-order logic, truth values are not objects in the domain, and so predicates (which output truth values) are intrinsically different from functions (which output domain elements). Therefore we need to know whether a symbol is supposed to represent a function or a predicate (and how many inputs it has), or of course a constant or variable.

Comment: But it is certainly possible, given a theory over a language with predicates, to construct an equivalent theory (with a computable translation) over a language where every $k$-input predicate is replaced by a $k$-input function, plus two special constants for denoting the possible truth value outputs of the original predicates.

Comment: Since any constant can be represented as a 0-ary function and all functions are themselves relations, technically the only thing a language requires is a set of relations. It is just more convenient to do it like Marker is doing it.

Comment: @HankIgoe: This is an ancient post, but technically you are wrong because we do not "require" relations, as per my earlier comment. Moreover, it's more convenient to drop relations rather than functions, otherwise you will have quite a lot of bloat when translating terms like "f(g(h(x,y)),u,v,w)". =)

Comment: If you dropped relations, how would you use a function to represent a relation which is not a function, e.g, R = <(0,0), (0,1)>?

Comment: Did you even **read** my first comment? It's totally trivial for anyone with a basic understanding of FOL.